# Is there a reverse geocoding service that lets me specify a lat/long bounding box?

Tags: reverse-geocoding, geocoding-service

I'd like to have all the street addresses within a given area, but I'm unable to determine if this is even possible. I can find many online services that given a specific latitude and longitude will return a single street address. The area I want this for in particular has approximately 500 residences, it's extremely tedious to attempt to compile the list by hand (and afterward, I may want another similar list later, I haven't decided).

The streets in question run parallel to north/south and east/west, so supplying the bounding box by either named streets or via latitude/longitude is simple enough.

Is there any easy way to obtain this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty unlikely you'll find a geocoding service that combines reverse geocoding with a bounding box, since the two concepts are somewhat at odds. There'd also be the question of what to do if the bounding box covers a large area, those queries might be too expensive for the provider to want to serve.

If the area you're interested in is in [OpenAddresses](https://openaddresses.io/), you might have reasonable luck downloading the relevant CSV file(s), reading through each line, and rejecting any rows that are outside your desired bounding box.

If the area you're interested in is has good address coverage in [OpenStreetMap](https://openstreetmap.org) (fairly rare outside of major cities and open data obsessed countries like Germany), you can use OverpassTurbo to query all addresses in an area [like this](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/VAX).

```
// Select any record with both a housenumber and street
nwr["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"]
  ({{bbox}});
out;
```

Comment: Thank you. The city I'm interested in is on OpenAddresses. It wasn't too difficult to filter the csv in Excel with my bounding box, and I'm seeing approximately as many addresses as I expected. I may also try the other method, it looks interesting.